# Drupal - where is text "Submitted by" coming from?

Tags: php, string, templates, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have news on my front page displayed by `Views` plugin. I found where is the template of views items (news) located. I overrided it with `node--news.tpl.php` where I can change the html of news item. But there is:

```
<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
  <span class="submitted"><?php print $submitted; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

piece of code that returns: `Submitted by Incredible on Tue, 03/10/2015 - 19:40`

In content settings is just:

**authored by**: *Incredible*
**authored on**: *2015-03-10 19:40:15 +0100*

Where is the string *Submitted by* coming from and how could I edit it?

Answer (score 0):

The $submitted variable is set in the default node preprocess function, [template_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7):

```
$variables['submitted'] = t('Submitted by !username on !datetime', array('!username' => $variables['name'], '!datetime' => $variables['date']));
```

You can overwrite the default by implementing [hook_preprocess_HOOK()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7) in your theme's template.php file as follows:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['submitted'] = // Your username logic here.
}
```